# C++ STL - How does the third parameter in fill() in the below program work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

In STL, the syntax for Fill is
template 
  void fill (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val);

The third parameter in the below program should be int.
What does it imply by the statement **operator int() const**? Can we have int as a function name? How does the return value of this function get converted to int and stored in a vector(As in third parameter of fill function)?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void print(int v) {
    cout << v << ", ";
}

struct Sequence {
    int start;
    Sequence(int a,int b): start(a) { }
    Sequence(int start) :start(start) {}
     operator int() const{
        return start;//LINE I
    }
};
int main() {
    vector<int> v1(7);
    fill(v1.begin(), v1.end(), Sequence(1,2));//LINE II
    for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), print);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WhiZTiM -- it's called a **conversion** operator. A cast is not the only thing that triggers a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Thanks for the correction. Noted!